# Custom exception render ignores validation messages

Tags: laravel, validation, exception

After adding a custom view for exception handling my validation messages no longer get returned, only - 'The given data failed to pass validation.'

I added the following to handler.php and removed the original parent::render($request, $exception);

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception){

    return response()->view('error', compact('exception'), 500);

}
```

Is there a way to keep my validation messages and display the error view when its not a validation failure as I hate seeing the default 'whoops an error has occured' view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work as intended, to keep my custom validation messages that were created by a FormRequest I had to add to my App/Exceptions/Handler.php:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if($exception instanceof ValidationException) {
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
    else{
        return response()->view('error', compact('exception'), 500);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look a bit further into the code of `parent::render()` , you'll see a line with:

```
return $this->convertValidationExceptionToResponse($e, $request);
```

This applies functions to the request like `withInput()` and `withErrors()`.

So, you could try some code similar to this:

```
public function render(...) {
  return response()->view('error', ...)
 ->withInput(Arr::except($request->input(), $this->dontFlash))
 ->withErrors($exception->errors(), $exception->errorBag);
}
```